# JQuery array of objects in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want an array of objects to be sent via post through ajax. Background story: a user selects a number of rooms, and those rooms should be booked in another file using php.
The array/objects is defined as:

```
var rooms = {};
rooms[rname] = 
                {
                        "rname": rname, // eg 1.27
                        "date": date, // eg 2013-04-24
                        "time": time, // eg 20:15
                        "duration": duration // eg 4
                }
```

And the ajax call is made

```
$.ajax({ 
         type: 'GET', //used get to see the parameters passed
         url: 'book_room.php',
         data: rooms
});
```

However, it seems that the request sent is somewhat like this:

> http://url.dk/book_room.php?1.29%5Brname%5D=1.29&1.29%5Bdate%5D=2013-04-28&1.29%5Btime%5D=20%3A15&1.29%5Bduration%5D=4&2.25%5Brname%5D=2.25&2.25%5Bdate%5D=2013-04-28&2.25%5Btime%5D=20%3A15&2.25%5Bduration%5D=4

How can I successfully pass a set of rooms in a request so I can work with them properly? I have a feeling that I have misunderstood the purpose of something here.

Comment: [Send and receive objects using JSON, AJAX, jquery and PHP](http://www.islandsmooth.com/2010/04/send-and-receive-json-data-using-ajax-jquery-and-php/)

Comment: You can only send strings, but jQuery automagically turns objects and arrays into valid strings to be sent to the serverside, and that's why when checking the request you see it as a querystring.

Comment: If you consider your question answered, you should post your solution as an answer. Otherwise, the correct interpretation is "I've solved this problem this way. How can I improve this solution?" and answers are allowed to refer to your solution as it's a part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As adviced I will post the fix for the problem as an answer.
I Found a solution where X requests are made based on how many rooms were chosen, and it works just fine.

```
$.each(rooms, function(k,v) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'book_room.php',
                        data: v
                    });
                });
```

The requests made this time looks easy to work with. Example requests:

> http://url.dk/book_room.php?rname=1.47&date=2013-04-28&time=21%3A00&duration=4
>   http://url.dk/book_room.php?rname=22.3&date=2013-04-28&time=21%3A00&duration=4

Answer (score 2):

Accorting to the API http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
You should POST like:

```
$.ajax({
    contentType:"application/json",
    url:yourEndPoint,
    data:JSON.stringify(yourStuffGoesHere),
    dataType:"json",
    processData:false,
});
```